# Batch rename “case duplicates”

Tags: bash, rename, mv

[Regarding this problem and answer:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188020/189709) https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188020/189709

```
for f in *; do mv --backup=numbered -- "$f" "${f,,}"; done
rename -v -- 's/\.~(\d+)~/$1/' *.~*~
```

mv: This command implicitly changes all filenames to lowercase. How to modify the options not to do that? The backup numbering is sufficient to distinguish the files.

rename: test.~1~ won't be renamed if a file test1 already exists. How to change the options to have test.~1~ renamed to test2?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. The filenames are lowercased _explicitly_ by `${f,,}`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I assume the OP was unaware of how the "implicit" Bash string manipulation syntax `${VAR<modifiers>}` works ...

Comment: @Kusalananda So how to change the destination operand of mv in order to have duplicated filenames renamed to .~1~ .~2~ .~3~ etc. without changing the filenames to lowercase? AdminBee is true, I am unaware of the bash sting manipulition syntax, that's why I ask

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at now. Good. Hmm... Could you show what your would want happen with the filenames `test`, `Test`, and `TEST` for example?

Comment: Given a directory with three files:
 Test1
 Test
 test
 .I want to mount this NTFS volume on Windows Home (i.e. not supporting fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo C:\folder enable). 
So I need unique filenames without case distinguation.
Step 1 (the mv command) renames the files to 
 test1
 test.~1~
 test
 .This command should not change cases.

Step 2 (rename) changes the backup numbering to a plain number at the end of the filename.
Here it atempts to change test.~1~ to test1
It fails because such a file already exists. 
So test11 or test2 would be feasible.

Comment: @Kusalananda   test, Test, and TEST  would change to test, test.~1~ and test.~2~ and in step 2 to test, test1 and test2

Comment: ... but you want to maintain the original case of the names?

Comment: @Kusalananda exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to implement your renaming strategy yourself since the code you are looking at explicitly lower-cases the filenames in the call to `mv` to catch duplicates in actual filename collisions.

The following only renames files if there are collisions, without actually causing the collisions (i.e. it does not fall back to GNU `mv` to handle the collisions):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# The suffix array contains a filename suffix (a positive integer)
# for each lower-cased filename.
declare -A suffix

# Get all names in the current directory.
set -- *

# Initialise the suffixes for each existing name to zero.
for name do
        suffix[${name,,}]=0
done

for name do

        # Loop until no name collision.
        while true; do
                # Get the current suffix for this filename.
                suf=${suffix[${name,,}]}

                # Increment the suffix for this filename.
                suffix[${name,,}]=$(( ${suffix[${name,,}]} + 1 ))

                # If the suffix is 0, empty it.
                [[ $suf == 0 ]] && suf=

                # Create the new name.
                newname=$name$suf

                # Break out of the loop if the name didn't change, or if
                # there's no other file that has this name.
                if [[ $name == "$newname" ]] ||
                   [[ -z ${suffix[${newname,,}]} ]]
                then
                        break
                fi
        done

        if [[ $name != "$newname" ]]; then
                printf '%s --> %s\n' "$name" "$newname"
                # uncomment the next line to actually do the renaming
                # mv -- "$name" "$newname"
        else
                printf '%s unchanged\n' "$name"
        fi

done
```

(note the commented out `mv`, you may want to run this with that line commented out until you are confident that it does the right thing)

Testing:

```
$ ls
A         Bb        TEST1     a         bb        test
BB        TEST      Test      bB        script.sh
```

```
$ bash script.sh
A unchanged
BB unchanged
Bb --> Bb1
TEST unchanged
TEST1 unchanged
Test --> Test2
a --> a1
bB --> bB2
bb --> bb3
script.sh unchanged
test --> test3
```

Comment: Thank you @kusalananda, you are a real bash pro!